# In my UILabel words that do not fit do not go to the next line

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

I have a custom cell that dynamically resizes itself based on the amount of lines in the UILabel. It words fine except for the fact that words that do not fit do not go to the next line instead they just get cut off. Example below.[image]

How do I have those words that get cut off go to the next line?

**EDIT: 11/29/15**  Added picture of entire Simulator by request of luk2303, and am using `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` for the label. The top cell seems to work fine but the bottom cell has words cut off. By the way there are 2 different labels in there if you couldn't tell.[image]

Comment: are you looking for the [line break mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode)?

Comment: I have tried all the line brake modes,  but none have seemed to work.  But yes that is what I am looking for.  I want to change how the label brakes lines.

Comment: can you show a image of the entire view? It may be that your label is wrapping the words correctly but the itself gets cut off from its superview.

Comment: I believe the one I want is `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` as it wraps words that don't fit to the next line,  but I haven't gotten it to work.

Comment: Are you sure the width of the label is correct? The text may be wrapping just fine but the label may be too wide.

Comment: The problem was I did not constrain the right side of the label to the right side of the cell. I will add an answer to my own question soon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I did not constrain the right side of the label in the storyboard to the right side of the cell. This resulted in the cell having a width that would extend beyond the right side of the cell making it look like the words did not wrap. Auto layout did not provide this for me, I had to add it myself.

Photo of working version below.

[image]

Comment: I will accept this answer as correct in 2 days when I am able, Thanks to @rmaddy for pointing out the width of the label.